# Deserialize an object logged in splunk

Tags: java, splunk

I have an object that is logged in splunk. It is a pretty large object.
looks something like this JobEntity(eventId=dc814fd9-91d2-4e4c-a2b1-7693248d, targetId=2345, status=CREATED, errorMessage=null....)

Is there a way i can deserialize this java object(JobEntity). I need to reconstruct this object to reproduce an issue using unit tests.

what i have tried so far:

1:

```
try {
      String objStr = FileUtil.readResourceFile("job/job_entity1.txt");
      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
      JobEntity job = objectMapper.readValue(objStr, JobEntity.class);
      System.out.println(job);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.err.println(ex);
    }
```

2:

```
    String filePath = "/job/job_entity1.txt";
    try {
      FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(filePath);
      ObjectInputStream reader = new ObjectInputStream(file);
      while (true) {
        try {
          JobEntity obj = (JobEntity)reader.readObject();
          System.out.println(obj);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
          System.err.println("end of reader file ");
          break;
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      System.err.println("failed to read " + filePath + ", "+ ex);
    }
```

Comment: is the event in Splunk valid JSON? What do you mean by "deserialize"?